# Ошибка после компиляции программы в pyinstaller

Tags: python, dll, компиляция, python-2.x, pyinstaller

После компиляции программы с помощью pyinstaller при запуске .exe файла выдаёт эту ошибку.
В моей программе имена модулей все на английском, не содержат символов юникода. Python 2.7 `32x` Windows 7 и 8. В чём проблема? Как исправить?

```
C:\Users\user\dist>sb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sb.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
  line 389, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 546, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Ššþø÷þ°õû žñþù ò ÿšþóšðüüõ øýø¡øðûø÷ð¡øø ñøñûøþªõú
ø ôøýðüø¢õžúþù úþüÿþýþòúø (DLL).
Failed to execute script sb
```

Использовал pyinstaller так: `путь_к_pyinstaller путь_к_py_файлу_программы`

Comment: где вы тут путь увидели? ImportError: DLL load failed, дальше пояснение ошибки с ошибкой кодировки.

Comment: @Igor, это запуск скомпилированной программы

Comment: не содержат символов юникода - в ошибке о них ничего не сказано. Из-за локали Россия вывод о том что это за ошибка выводится русским текстом.

Comment: В чём проблема? Как исправить? ImportError: DLL load failed - не загружена библиотека, если сами ничего лишнего не подключаете, значит не все необходимые зависимости указаны при сборке.

Comment: @Igor, используются библиотеки pygame, numpy, noise

Comment: module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple) - вот эта строка к какой библиотеке относится, ее принудительно подключите в файл сборки.

Comment: @Igor, как это сделать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44070/discussion-between-igor-and-mihail-ris).